# Is it possible to trigger a Lambda function on a VPC creation/ edit event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a Lambda function that I want to take action on a transit gateway when a new VPC is created, or when a VPC is updated. I've used CloudWatch Events for similar triggers in the past (such as when an EC2 instance was terminated) and was hoping to do something similar for this use case. What I've found is that VPC is not listed as one of the services available in Events, and the CloudTrail trail I have configured doesn't appear to be catching CreateVpc or DeleteVpc events, so I'm not sure that using the CloudTrail event pattern is possible either.

I was hoping to use an event similar to what's below, but have not had any luck -

```
{
  "source": ["aws.cloudtrail"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["CreateVpc"]
  }
}
```

Is it possible to catch a CreateVpc event for use as a Lambda trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> doesn't appear to be catching CreateVpc or DeleteVpc events

You have to double check your trail setup. `CreateVpc` and `DeleteVpc` are for sure captured by the CloudTrial.

However, it may be problem with your rule. The **source should** be `aws.ec2`:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ec2"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["ec2.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["CreateVpc"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Marcin. Perhaps this is a stupid question, but is there any reason these events wouldn’t show up in the Event History in the CloudTrail console? I’ve checked both a work and personal account, both of which have global trails configured. I’ll definitely update my event, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Turns out I couldn't see the events because even though the trail was global, I needed to be in the same region in CloudTrail console as where the event happened. I knew it was something dumb. Your event advice got me my first successful trigger, thank you so much!

Comment: @SomeDudeFromtheInternet No problem. Glad it worked out:-)